# DART: How to setup Gerrit/Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, dart, gerrit

to setup a gated checkin, we would like to use Gerrit and Jenkins. We have experience about how to do this with JavaScript, but Dart is completely new to us.

So far I haven't seen a dart plugin for Jenkins for central build and triggering the code checks. How do you guys setup the systems to allow both code checks and central build?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there, do you need additional information from my side or is there really no one out there who has experience in setting up a central build landscape for dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://drone.io to automatically build dart projects on push to github pretty seamlessly.

I haven't done it with Jenkins yet but I know you can set Jenkins to watch for changes on a git or hg repo then run a script build. A script would just need dart/bin on the path to run `pub build`

A plugin would just be for the dart build part which is that fairly simple script or a hop task runner script so it's probably just hasn't been a big deal to make a Jenkins plugin.

Comment: Cheers for the hint. I will follow this way and check if it suits our needs.